# How to 'import *' and call imported functions when package is directory not file

Tags: python, import, client-server, package

If I'm developing a client-server app and have 3 files (`client.py`, `server.py`, and `common.py,`) and `common.py` has a useful function (e.g. `normalize()`), it's easy from both client and server to do something like this:

```
from common import *

url = normalize(url)
```

However if, for various strange reasons, I'd rather have separate subdirectories (`client`, `server`, and `common`), and each function had its own file, there doesn't seem to be a similar shortcut.

I have to fiddle with `sys.path`, then after the import I need to use `url=normalize.normalize(url)`. I'm sure I could program a workaround, but is there already some Pythonic way of handling this that I'm unaware of?

**Update:** here's how I did it after following Ignacio's advice below:

```
$ cat common/__init__.py; client/login.py jcomeauictx.myopenid.com
import os, sys
for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
 print >>sys.stderr, 'module: %s' % module
 name, extension = os.path.splitext(module)
 if extension == '.py' and not name.startswith('_'):
  importer = 'from %s import %s' % (name, name)
  print >>sys.stderr, 'import statement: %s' % importer
  exec(importer)
```

Result:

```
module: __init__.py
module: normalize.py
import statement: from normalize import normalize
module: __init__.pyc
module: normalize.pyc
('http://www.myopenid.com/server', 'http://jcomeauictx.myopenid.com/')
```

Comment: Why would one create one file per function? This either means that your functions are too big or you'll get hundreds of files altogether.

Comment: because I'm various and strange.

Comment: Well, if you're strange enough you could patch Python so you can write syntax like this: `from common import *, *.*` :D. Anyway, having one file per function surely isn't pythonic IMO.

Comment: @AndiDog: I assumed he meant that each module contained unique collections of functionality, not that they each had only one "def" block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything the `__init__.py` within the directory imports will be imported on `import *` provided it's not restricted by `__all__`.

Answer (score 0):

Move `client.py` to `client/__init__.py`, `server.py` to `server/__init__.py` and `common` to `common/__init__.py` and all will work as before.

As far as naming is concerned, `client.py` is a module called `client`, `client/__init__.py` is part of a package called `client`. You could then add `client/something.py` and have `import client`, `import client.something`, `from client import something` and things like that. The general way of doing things is also to have `client/__init__.py` just pulling things together:

`client/__init__.py`:

```
from client.foo import *
from client import bar
```

`client/foo.py`:

```
__all__ = ('baz',)

def baz(): pass
```

`client/bar.py`:

```
def something(): pass
```

This can then be used like this:

```
import client
client.baz()
client.bar.something()
from client import bar
bar is client.bar
from client import foo
foo.baz is client.baz
```

It's helpful at times to look at the standard library and see how such features are used.

Comment: I'd use relative imports instead, if available.

Comment: @Ignacio: precisely, if available. For reference, that would be `from .foo import *` and `from . import bar` in `client/__init__.py`. See [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).